# Nvidia Driver update problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have been using ubuntu for mining with T-rex miner and overclocking with GreenWithEnvy which give me a hashrate of 43.9 for ethereum. This was with nvidia 470 driver whole system was very very stable. Yesterday I upgraded my nvidia drivers to 510 which is the latest. With this upgrade, GreenWithEnvy app has stopped working and so I reverted back to 470 but the stability of my system has been lost. I think it could be because of some parts of 510 which are retained. Is there a way to completely roll back the 510 upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the proprietary nvidia packages run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot
```

nvidia-driver-470 can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To reinstall the nvidia-driver-470 metapackage which depends on the NVIDIA binary driver and on all of its libraries run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470 
sudo reboot
```